# Time zone changing arbitrarily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I'm using the gem [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/) to do a query like this in a controller's action:

```
Event.where.not(user_id: [1, 3]).group_by_week(:created_at, week_start: :mon, last: 13, reverse: true).count
```

Doing a couple of sequential queries by refreshing the webpage changes the SQL query from time to time. What seems to be changing is the app's default time zone, and this happens without me even setting the time zone in this action/view.

What can be the reason for this? How/where could I debug this?

UTC is set in `application.rb` as default time zone. An example of two different SQL queries caused by the same query above:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 day' - INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 day' + INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' AS date_trunc_week_created_at_timestamptz_interval_0_day_interval_ FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."user_id" NOT IN (1, 3, 290, 339)) AND (created_at >= '2017-07-31 00:00:00' AND created_at <= '2017-10-25 22:23:42.184226') GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 day' - INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC') + INTERVAL '0 day' + INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 day' - INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') + INTERVAL '0 day' + INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' AS date_trunc_week_created_at_timestamptz_interval_0_day_interval_ FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."user_id" NOT IN (1, 3, 290, 339)) AND (created_at >= '2017-07-31 04:00:00' AND created_at <= '2017-10-25 22:24:57.912750') GROUP BY (DATE_TRUNC('week', (created_at::timestamptz - INTERVAL '0 day' - INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York') + INTERVAL '0 day' + INTERVAL '0 second') AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York'
```

Comment: https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/lib/groupdate/magic.rb#L203

Comment: Thanks, but why would the time zone change arbitrarily? Do you mean that the answer is to be found in that method of the source code?

Answer (score 1):

the method `def time_zone` is from the `class Magic`, it has an`attr_accessor :options`. When you create the instance `@magic = Magic.new(period, options)` you set in the `options` parameters your timezone either to `true` or `false` or to some other value

based on this parameter the [`def time_zone`](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/lib/groupdate/magic.rb#L203) method is going to set and return `@time_zone`

```
def time_zone
  @time_zone ||= begin
    time_zone = "Etc/UTC" if options[:time_zone] == false
    time_zone ||= options[:time_zone] || Groupdate.time_zone || (Groupdate.time_zone == false && "Etc/UTC") || Time.zone || "Etc/UTC"
    time_zone.is_a?(ActiveSupport::TimeZone) ? time_zone : ActiveSupport::TimeZone[time_zone]
  end
end
```

**you set the timezone with `Groupdate.time_zone`.**
`:time_zone` is an attr_accessor from module [`Groupdate`](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate/blob/master/lib/groupdate.rb)

```
module Groupdate
  class Error < RuntimeError; end

  PERIODS = [:second, :minute, :hour, :day, :week, :month, :quarter, :year, :day_of_week, :hour_of_day, :minute_of_hour, :day_of_month, :month_of_year]
  # backwards compatibility for anyone who happened to use it
  FIELDS = PERIODS
  METHODS = PERIODS.map { |v| :"group_by_#{v}" } + [:group_by_period]

  mattr_accessor :week_start, :day_start, :time_zone, :dates
  self.week_start = :sun
  self.day_start = 0
  self.dates = true
end
```

and that is where the method `def time_zone` inside `magic.rb` is searching for the value...

```
time_zone ||= options[:time_zone] || Groupdate.time_zone || (Groupdate.time_zone == false && "Etc/UTC") || Time.zone || "Etc/UTC"
```

As you can see from the expression above, it is either the `options[:time_zone]` from the instance of `Magic`, or the `Groupdate.time_zone` from the `Groupdate` module, or it is either `Time.zone` from your server or desktop, or `Etc/UTC`

So I think that you can solve this by just following the guide, that gives you two options:

### Solution

> ## [Time Zones](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate#time-zones)
>
> The default time zone is Time.zone. Change this with:

```
Groupdate.time_zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

or

```
User.group_by_week(:created_at, time_zone: "Pacific Time (US & Canada)").count
# {
#   Sun, 06 Mar 2016 => 70,
#   Sun, 13 Mar 2016 => 54,
#   Sun, 20 Mar 2016 => 80
# }
```

> Time zone objects also work. To see a list of available time zones in Rails, run rake time:zones:all.